# access to generic form field in template

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a form with generic fields

forms.py

```
 class OfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
           model=Offer
```

some_views.py

```
  def add_field(request):
        form = OfferForm()
        #some logic here
        for x in list:
               form.fields[x]=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=some_query)
        return render_to_response(template,{'form':form,'list_of_add_field':list}
```

So , In my template i want to do something like this:

```
 {%for x in list_of_add_field%}
 Name add field is {{x}}
 Choices:
{%for y in form.{{x}}.choices %}
     <input type="checkbox" name="form.{{x}}.html_name">y </input>
 {%endfor%}
 {%endfor%}
```

How can do that ? Any idea ?
Thank you !

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's `list` in your view? Why are you defining form fields in your view and not in your forms.py. Why don't you use django's approach to displaying forms in the template

Comment: Why am defining form fields in view ? OK, I need dynamic form like http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/  because I need add various option to offer depends what "list" contain.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are intended to do and here my reply. You should adapt your code to django and not django to your code. In this way, to solve your issue, the 'prefix' form resource is the right option:

You can put several Django forms inside one  tag. To give each Form its own namespace, use the prefix keyword argument:

```
>>> mother = PersonForm(prefix="mother")
>>> father = PersonForm(prefix="father")
>>> print mother.as_ul()
<li><label for="id_mother-first_name">First name:</label> <input type="text" name="mother-first_name" id="id_mother-first_name" /></li>
<li><label for="id_mother-last_name">Last name:</label> <input type="text" name="mother-last_name" id="id_mother-last_name" /></li>
>>> print father.as_ul()
<li><label for="id_father-first_name">First name:</label> <input type="text" name="father-first_name" id="id_father-first_name" /></li>
<li><label for="id_father-last_name">Last name:</label> <input type="text" name="father-last_name" id="id_father-last_name" /></li>
```

In your case, you can make a new form for each X of your list. Put all new forms in a list named formset. Then, in your template, you should write form loop:

```
{{for form in formset}}
    ... Here your code for a form ....
```